# How to make a certain pulse function with Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How to make a certain pulse function with Matlab, like this function on the graph:

[image: pulse graph]

I have the function which generates a pulse, but I want to generate as the graph above

```
clear all; clc; close all
% Step 1: Calculate Fourier Transform Coefficients
N = 101; % Number of coefficients
D = [];
% Negative Coefficients
for n = -(N-1)/2 : -1
D = [D (1/(n*pi))*sin(n*pi/2)];
end
% Append D0
D0 = 0.5; D = [D D0];
% Positive Coefficients
for n = 1 : (N-1)/2
D = [D (1/(n*pi))*sin(n*pi/2)];
end
% Step 2: Calculate the series terms
series = [];
f0 = 1; % Frequency in Hz
T0 = 1/f0; % Period in seconds
dt = T0/100; % Sample interval
t = -T0 : dt : T0;
for n = -(N-1)/2 : (N-1)/2
r = n + (N+1)/2;
temp = D(r)*exp(j*n*2*pi*f0*t);
series = [series; temp];
end
% Step 3: Summation of the series terms
w = 8*sum(series);
% Step 4: Plot the approximated signal
plot(t,w); grid
xlabel('Time, seconds'); ylabel('signal, s(t)')
title('An approximation of a rectangular singal using Fourier series')'
```

Comment: That code doesn't generate that figure. It creates a signal from the truncated fourier series of a square wave.

Comment: I know but the qution is how i can modefi the code to generate a function like the figure??

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the continuous Fourier series for your waveform, then modify the coefficients in `D` to match.

You can find information on general Fourier series elsewhere on the internet.